# The IControllerFactory 'System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Home'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I am working on ASP.net MVC codefirst application, I deployed 2 weeks before to live server it was working fine, after that I have made changes, in DB controllers view etc but not in routing and any Global.asax
deployed again today now getting this error

The IControllerFactory 'System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Home'.
[image]

dont know how to trace the issue

on local development server it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem
Actually there was issue with DB Connectionstring

Answer (score 0):

For further use of developers facing this issue, you may want to check the versions of your libraries from the nuget and your web.config file.